# Number to char implicit conversion in pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I m creating a stored procedure which  calculates total amount based on bonus and salary.
Stored procedure is created as below:

```
        Create or replace procedure cal_sum( p_salary in number, p_bonus inout number, p_output out number)
         Begin
         p_bonus :=p_salary*bonus/100;
         p_output :=p_bonus+p_salary;
         End;
```

And the stored procedure is invoked using anonymous block as below:

```
          Declare
          v_salary number := 2000;
          v_bonus number  := 10;
          v_total char(10);
          Begin
          cal_sum(v_salary,v_bonus,v_total);
           End;
```

The above procedure works fine, there is no compile time error . 
What I dint understand in the above query is how **query works even though the data types are different for p_output and v_total parameters in stored procedure and anonymous block respectively 
Does pl/sql support implicit conversion of number to char  ??
plz help**

Comment: There are multiple available articles with in-depth walkthroughs of implicit conversion.   http://intermediatesql.com/oracle/how-oracle-implicit-type-conversion-works-part-1/

Comment: Wouldn't a function be more suitable than a stored procedure for what you are attempting?

Comment: The above query is just an example , to illustrate the scenario of data type conversion

Comment: The only thing about implicit data type conversion you need to remember: avoid it. Any code relying on it should fail in a code review.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your simple question. The below example illustrates your dilemma :)

```
    SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    SQL> DECLARE
      2  lv_number NUMBER:='12345';
      3  BEGIN
      4  dbms_output.put_line(lv_number);
      5  END;
      6  /
    12345
```

See even though vv_number is of NUMBER datatype but still i have assigned that in ''.
So Oracle runs through its intelligence :P i.e conversion by its own. But same if you try with below example

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf
SQL> DECLARE
  2  lv_number NUMBER:='12345a';
  3  BEGIN
  4  dbms_output.put_line(lv_number);
  5  END;
  6  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Now you can see the clear difference that while converting 12345a as a NUMBER it failed.